# Python conflicting module names in editable dependencies

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have 2 separate Python packages, both of which I develop. Let's say PackageA is a package that I created, and PackageB is a forked version of a public package in which I changed a few things. PackageA relies on the changed version of PackageB. Originally, this was the package structure:

```
PackageA/
    __init__.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        separate_utils.py
    scripts/
        __init__.py
        script.py
    PackageB/
        lib/
            utils.py
        package/
            class.py
```

In Package B, `class.py` imports functions from `utils.py`. In `script.py`, I use functions from both `separate_utils.py`, but I also use the `class.py` module. With this original package structure, in `script.py`, I have these imports:

```
from lib.separate_utils import random_function
from PackageB.package import class
```

However, in `class.py`, there is this import statement:

```
from lib import utils
```

Because of my directory structure, it tries to import `utils` from `PackageA/lib` instead of `PackageA/PackageB/lib`, which causes an error to be thrown (`cannot import name 'utils' from 'lib'`). As a result, I changed my directory structure so that PackageB is an editable package.

```
Random folder/
    PackageA/
        __init__.py
        lib/
            __init__.py
            separate_utils.py
            scripts/
            __init__.py
            script.py
    PackageB/
        __init__.py
        lib/
            utils.py
        package/
            class.py
        setup.py
```

However, even after successfully installing with `pip install -e [path_to_PackageB]`, I get the exact `cannot import name 'utils' from 'lib'` error. I cannot figure out why this is happening, and I've read through all of the Python modules documentation, as well as a ton of different StackOverflow questions and blog posts.

I've tried different permutations of things such as `from __future__ import absolute_import`, including empty `__init__.py` files in every directory, and using `sys.path.insert` and `sys.path.append`, all to no avail.

Comment: `from PackageB.lib import utils`

Comment: @SebastianLoehner I don't think that makes sense. While in theory it would work, 1. I shouldn't have to reference the name of a package to access a module in the same package and 2. I'm trying to avoid changing the structure and imports of PackageB since it's forked from a public repo

Comment: If you want to avoid changing `package_b` why not add a `utils` into `package_a` which just imports the proper one?

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I don't think that would work? `class.py` depends on `PackageB/lib/utils.py`, and I don't see how adding a `PackageA/lib/utils.py` would help.